# AVAudioPlayer is nil after viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer, null

I'm using the latest Xcode, Xcode 5.0.2, I test it with iPad Simulator 7.0, my audio file
is m4a, imported & written with GarageBand on my iPad, but when I tried to play it, it goes
nil, I imported AVFoundation.framework to my project, here is the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface NastyCansViewController : UIViewController
{
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}
@end
```

here is the .m file. I use NSLog to see if my audioPlayer is nil.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *songURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/song.m4a"], NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSError * error
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentOfURL:songURL error:&error];
    if (audioPlayer == nil) {
        NSLog(@"audioPlayer is nil");
    }
}
```

When I ran the app, NSLog appeared and displayed "audioPlayer is nil"
I also tried a lot of other code but all I get is nil, please help, thank you

Comment: Is `error` set after you attempt to create the `AVAudioPlayer`? If so, what is it telling you?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
NSLog(@"audioPlayer is nil");
```

with following code to get error information:

```
NSLog(@"audioPlayer init error:%@", error);
```

try this to implement the function:

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]
                                             options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                               error:&error];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
if (audioPlayer == nil) {
    NSLog(@"audioPlayer is init error:%@", error);
}
```